# rviz seg faults after implementing "PointCloud2 display, and set the topic to /camera/depth/points"

Tags: ros, rviz, pointcloud, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I get a segmentation fault error and rviz closes whenever I run the openni_launch. The steps I take are

1. roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
2. rosrun rviz rviz
3. Set the Fixed Frame (top left of rviz window) to /camera_depth_optical_frame.
4. Add a PointCloud2 display, and set the topic to /camera/depth/points

After these steps rviz crashes with a segfault error. Can anyone help? Below are some more info

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/690101082ba53f5c395d0b045247d82a

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130831/rviz-seg-faults-after-implementing-%22pointcloud2-display,-and-set-the-topic-to-/camera/depth/points%22/) by [nasticy](https://answers.ros.org/users/11746/nasticy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PointCloud display on rviz/groovy installed from .debs currently seems to be broken (on non-Nvidia GPU machines). I also encountered this issue few days ago and "solved" it by using hydro instead. See [this related Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/126766/ros-rviz-groovy-segfault-and-assertion-fail/) and rviz tickets [713](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/713) and [717](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/717).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0